# c# - Why does Directory.GetFiles() invert the / before the filename

Tags: c#

I am using Directory.GetFiles() to get all the .dat files from a folder. But when I loop trough the filenames the last / is made into an \ , why is this happening?

```
string[] fileNames = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.dat");
```

**Path**

> D:/Project/TestProject

**fileNames[0]**

> D:/Project/TestProject\test.dat

Comment: Windows uses backslash while internet uses forward slashes.  You may have a shared folder so the shared folder is using forward slash (over internet) while windows using backslashes.

Comment: In addition to the answer, it also seems that your relative path is actually a hard-coded absolute path.

Comment: @jdweng: While it prefers the backslash (Path.DirectorySeparatorChar), it does seem to accept the Slash as well (Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Directory.GetFiles` keeps the path you pass into it as is but for every part it appends itself, it uses the OS directory separator, which is `\` on Windows.

`/` and `\` are both valid as path separators in .NET (they are `Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar` and `Path.DirectorySeparatorChar` respectively). The [documentation for `Path.DirectorySeparatorChar`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.directoryseparatorchar?view=netframework-4.8#remarks) has this to say about which to chose:

> When you are using .NET Core to develop applications that run on
>   multiple platforms:
>
> - If you prefer to hard-code the directory separator character, you should use the forward slash (/) character. It is the only recognized
>     directory separator character on Unix systems, as the output from the
>     example shows, and is the AltDirectorySeparatorChar on Windows.
>
> [...]
>
> If your application is not cross-platform, you can use the separator appropriate for your system.

Comment: Specifically it uses the value of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.directoryseparatorchar | But it will also accept the value of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.altdirectoryseparatorchar in paths it is given. | There is even a advice to default to "/" as it will work on Windows and Unix. | Both being initonly does allow the value to change each programm execution, but not during: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/initonly-cpp-cli